# Insert into #tmp table using lin2db

Tags: linq2db

I have a set of tables I need to run some queries against. 
2-3 tables used are the same so makes sense to create a tmp table (limited access to the server so no views, stored proc solutions please).
Any idea how to achieve that using linq2db?
TIA

Comment: You have typo in topic. The question is: How to create temporary table by linq2db? But do you have rights to do this if you have limited access? Do you can create your own view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (var db = new DataConnection()
{
    var tempTable = db.CreateTable<MyTempTable("#tmp");

    (
        from t in ...
        select t...
    ).Insert(tempTable, t => new MyTempTable { Field1 = t.... });
}
```